# Why won't my php function call with javascript button work?

Tags: php, javascript, function

I'm trying to call a php function which increments a database entry by 1 when a javascript button is clicked so the result is displayed on my page, the button, however, does nothing. Could you tell me what is causing the problem in the code below?

I realize this is probably a noob question but I did my share of research and this is the furthest I got with my low level of knowledge (I'm only beginning to learn), thus I'll be most grateful for any hints on what I should correct or learn.

```
  <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("XXX","XXX","XXX","XXX");
?>

<?php
function addOne()
{
global $con;
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE voting SET A=A+1");
 }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM voting");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['A'];
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>

<script>
function increment()
{
  <?php addOne();?>;
}
</script>

<button onclick="increment()">VOTE</button>
```

Comment: Try viewing source of your page in a browser

Comment: Basic concept is that php code runs in server and java script in browser.So you have to make a ajax call from browser(javascript) to server (php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: Why does the PHP (or other server side) code in my Javascript not work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/reference-why-does-the-php-or-other-server-side-code-in-my-javascript-not-wor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use AJAX to do that.

Something like:

```
function increment(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "example.com/increment.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            //
        }
    });
}
```

And then on the server side, in some PHP file such as `increment.php`, you can update your database. Note that this example uses jQuery.

Comment: Thank you - this is most helpful. I think I will manage now.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server side, JavaScript is client side. You can't call javascript function using php and you can't call PHP function using javascript, they works separately.

When you use

```
<?php addOne();?>;
```

You are just printing the result of the php function in the html code, nothing else.
If you want to call the php function, you have to use an AJAX call, or a form submission.